# Junit for Solr Indexing Documents from AEM

Tags: junit, solr, aem

I have my ServiveImpl class, which has public methods to create and delete index from AEM to Solr. How can we handle the Junit for these void methods using Mockito?  Any pointers will be help.  Mainly for testing integration with Solr

Comment: what is the expected outcome? do you want an integration test of the search indexing or do you want to mock the interaction and assert on something else?

Comment: Can we mock the document and assert create and delete index?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your JUnit wouldn't really make any difference other than giving you some test coverage.

The reason behind writing a Junit is to ensure that a method returns a result, or throws an exception. With a void method, the only thing that can be tested is that the method executes.

To solve this, it would be good to at least return a boolean value. Without this, you can never be sure whether the index was really deleted or not.

So the suggestion here would be-

1. Update the method to ensure the correct error handling takes place.
2. Based on the method execution, return a boolean value at least. This will not have any impact on your project because the method was `void` anyway and no calls would be impacted.
3. In your Junit, assert the returned value as `true` or `false`, or just use the `assertTrue` method.

```
boolean deleteIndex(String indexName) {

    if (deleted) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

JUnit-

```
@InjectMocks
private ServiveImpl service = new ServiveImpl();

@Test
public void testIndexDeletion() {

    boolean indexDeleted = ServiveImpl.deleteIndex("someIndex");
    assertTrue(indexDeleted);
    
}
```